# Set project variables for GULP on postbuild event in project.json

Tags: visual-studio, gulp, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a new `vNext` project. I want to set a variable for `gulp` into the `process.env`.

In previous versions of the framework I could use `Target-Exec` combination to do it:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
   <Exec Command='gulp --env="$(Configuration)|$(Platform)"' />
</Target>
```

(Un)fortunately `vNext` does not support `.csproj` files (what I personally think is a blessing:D).

I want do the same as above in `vNext` > `gulpfile.js`.

I have my `project.json`, but I don't know if I can use `Visual Studio` global variables inside (I'm afraid I do not...).

I tried [THIS DOC](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file):

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postbuild": "my command"
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work for me. I also tried `echo test` to check if the event works. Nothing happened...

Even if it starts working, there is a problem about the variables. They said I can use only these:

```
%project:Directory% - The project directory
%project:Name% - The project name
%project:Version% - The project version
```